# SqlDependency OnChange Not Firing

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sqldependency

This is the first time I've ever needed to use an SqlDependency so I am hoping that its a stupid mistake I've made.

The problem I'm having is that the OnChanged event doesn't fire when the sql table changes. No errors or anything just it doesn't fire.

Here is the code

```
public class SqlWatcher
{
    private const string SqlConnectionString = "Data Source = CN-PC08\\DEV; Initial Catalog=DEP; User = sa; Password=******";

    public SqlWatcher()
    {
        SqlClientPermission perm = new SqlClientPermission(System.Security.Permissions.PermissionState.Unrestricted);
        perm.Demand();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [DataAvaliable], [RowNumber] FROM [dbo].[Trigger]", new SqlConnection(SqlConnectionString));
        SqlDependency sqlDependency = new SqlDependency(cmd);
        sqlDependency.OnChange += On_SqlBitChanged;
    }

    private void On_SqlBitChanged(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs sqlNotificationEventArgs)
    {
        SqlDependency dependency = (SqlDependency)sender;
        dependency.OnChange -= On_SqlBitChanged;

        // Fire the event
        if (NewMessage != null)
        {
            NewMessage(this, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        SqlDependency.Start(SqlConnectionString);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        SqlDependency.Stop(SqlConnectionString);
    }

    public event EventHandler NewMessage;
```

And in my main window I have this

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        try
        {
            SqlWatcher sqlWatcher = new SqlWatcher();
            sqlWatcher.Start();
            sqlWatcher.NewMessage += On_NewMessage;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }

    private void On_NewMessage(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Message Received");
    }
}
```

So the expected behaviour is that if I run the following sqlQuery a messageBox will be displayed saying "Message Received"

```
INSERT INTO [DEP].[dbo].[Trigger] Values(0,3)
```

Could anyone give me a hint on what to check/change?

I'm aware that only a subset of Sql features can be used in dependencies but I don't think I'm trying to do anything to fancy here.

Comment: Think anyone trying to look for a workaround for sqldependency, should use sqldependencyEx. Easy connectivity steps can be found here. 

https://github.com/dyatchenko/ServiceBrokerListener

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> I'm hoping that its a stupid mistake I've made.

Unfortunately (or fortunately?) you are making several mistakes.

1. First is you need to understand that Query Notifications will invalidate **one query**. So you will only be notified at most *once* and you have to re-subscribe again (re-submit the query) if you want to receive further notifications.
2. Next you need to understand that you will be notified for *any* reason, not only for changes. In your callback you *must* check the reason you're notified, which are passed in via the `SqlNotificationEventArgs`.
3. Next you need to understand asynchronous programming basic principles: if you subscribe for an event make sure you subscribe **before** the event can happen first time. Case in point: the `On_SqlBitChanged` can fire **as soon as you submit the query**. This *should* happen in the `SqlWatcher.SqlWatcher` constructor, but you subscribe to the `sqlWatcher.NewMessage` *after* the constructor runs. `On_SqlBitChanged` can be invoked between the constructor finishes before you hook up the `NewMessage` event callback in which case the notification is silently ignored.
4. If you want to use a service make sure you start it **before** you use it. You are using SqlDependency in `SqlWatcher.SqlWatcher` but you start it *after* that when you call `SqlWatcher.Start()`.
5. Finally, if you want to be notified of changes on a query **you have to submit the query**. You are constructing the `SqlCommand` object, set up the notification and then... discard the object. Unless you actually submit the query, you did not yet subscribed to *anything*.

Suggestions for fix:

- Make `Start` and `Stop` statics, call `Start` in application start up.
- Make sure you subscribe to `NewMessage` *before* you submit the query
- Actually submit the query (call `SqlComamnd.ExecuteQuery()`)
- Inspect the `Info`, `Type` and `Source` in the `On_SqlBitChanged` callback, if your submission contains an error this is the only way to learn (the SqlComamnd.ExecuteQuery() will succeed even if the notification request is invalid)
- You must re-subscribe once you're notified of a change, execute the query again.

One more thing: don't invoke UI code in background callbacks. You cannot call `MessageBox.Show("Message Received");` from a callback, you must route through the form main thread via [`Form.Invoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.invoke.aspx). YEs, I know that strictly speaking `MessageBox.Show` *does* work on a non-UI thread but you will soon move away from alert boxes to actually form interaction and then things will break.