# SqlDependency with signalR not firing dependency_OnChange consistently

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, signalr, c#-2.0

**Setup**

•Visual Studio 2010

•IIS 8.5

•.NET Framework 4.6

•Microsoft SQL Server 2014

•AppPool Account on IIS is domain\web

I have a web page that monitors changes in a database table. I am using dependency_OnChange to monitor the database and pass the data to the user via signalR. I set a breakpoint in the dependency_OnChange method and it is only getting hit a few times out of thousands of database updates.

In web.config... I am using Integrated Security=True.

My user is a sysadmin on the sql box. (This is just for proof of concept)

In Global.asax... specifying a queuename and stopping and starting sqldependency

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var queuename = "Q_Name";
    var sConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["singalR_ConnString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlDependency.Stop(sConn, queuename);
    SqlDependency.Start(sConn, queuename);
}

void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    var queuename = "Q_Name";
    var sConn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["singalR_ConnString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlDependency.Stop(sConn, queuename);
}
```

In code behind...

```
public void SendNotifications()
{
    //Identify Current User and Row No
    string CurrentUser = GetNTName();


    string message = string.Empty;
    string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["singalR_ConnString"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(conStr))
    {
        string query = "SELECT [RowNo] FROM [dbo].[Test] WHERE [User] =  @User";
        string SERVICE_NAME = "Serv_Name";

        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
        {
            // Add parameters and set values.
            command.Parameters.Add("@User", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = CurrentUser;
            //Need to clear notification object
            command.Notification = null;
            //Create new instance of sql dependency eventlistener (re-register for change events)
            SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command, "Service=" + SERVICE_NAME + ";", 0);
            //SqlDependency dependency = new SqlDependency(command);
            //Attach the change event handler which is responsible for calling the same SendNotifications() method once a change occurs.
            dependency.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
            connection.Open();
            SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                reader.Read();
                message = reader[0].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
    //If query returns rows, read the first result and pass that to hub method - NotifyAllClients.
    NotificationsHub nHub = new NotificationsHub();
    nHub.NotifyAllClients(message);
}


private void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{            
    //Check type to make sure a data change is occurring
    if (e.Type == SqlNotificationType.Change)
    {
        // Re-register for query notification SqlDependency Change events.
        SendNotifications();
    }
}
```

NotificationsHub.cs page...

```
    //Create the Hub
    //To create a Hub, create a class that derives from Microsoft.Aspnet.Signalr.Hub. 

//Alias that can call class from javascript. - i.e.  var hub = con.createHubProxy('DisplayMessage');
[HubName("DisplayMessage")]
public class NotificationsHub : Hub //Adding [:Hub] let c# know that this is a Hub 
{
    //In this example, a connected client can call the NotifyAllClients method, and when it does, the data received is broadcasted to all connected clients.

    //Create NotifyAllClients Method
    //public means accessible to other classes
    //void means its not returning any data
    public void NotifyAllClients(string msg)
    {
        IHubContext context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationsHub>();
        //When this method gets called, every single client has a function displayNotification() that is going to be executed
        //msg is the data that is going to be displayed to all clients.
        context.Clients.All.displayNotification(msg);                                                       
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I would do here is refactor the Sql Dependency setup out to a stand alone method and call it from your send notification. (SoC and DRY) because if you are creating other SqlDependencies in other places they are going to trip each other up. Secondly your are creating a new NotificationsHub, You should be getting the currently active hub.

```
DefaultHubManager hubManager = new DefaultHubManager();
hub = hubManager.ResolveHub("NotificationsHub");
hub.NotifyAllClients(message);
```

There is also an older way to get the hub but I am not sure it will still work

```
GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationsHub>()
```

I also have an example of a simpler version in this answer. 
[Polling for database changes: SqlDependency, SignalR is Good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22198423/polling-for-database-changes-sqldependency-signalr-is-good/24250011#24250011)

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response.

Comment: I modified my code to reflect your suggestion in regards to resolving the hub.  When the line hub.NotifyAllClients(message) is run I get the error: object not set to an instance of an object.  My NotificationsHub class is not static so I need to instantiate an instance of the class.   My original example had this: NotificationsHub nHub = new NotificationsHub();... but now I am not using it.  How can I go about doing this?  Also, I apologize for not knowing this, but how can I paste another code sample so that I can show you my NotificationsHub class?

Comment: Edit your original question and add it.

Comment: @RobC I added the old way to my answer, but I am not sure if it still works, or if it will work in your situation.

Comment: I am already using [ GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<NotificationsHub>() ] and this will only work if the class is not static and I go back to using [ NotificationsHub nHub = new NotificationsHub();...  ].  How can I integrate the resolve hub with my NotificationsHub : Hub?

Comment: You should not need to get a new context from inside your hub, it should already know, Try taking the context out, and just using Clients.All.displayNotification(msg); I get the impression there are multiple instances of your hub being created, and its getting confused. Try and do a simpler test project, get your hub working without SQLDependency, once you have that working consistently add the sql dependency in and see what happens.

Comment: The hub does work, just not all of the time.  I am able to relay the # of active connections successfully and consistently.  I could not get your example of the resolve hub to work but I was able to add code to only declare an instance of the hub class when null and it appears that this is only getting the active hub.  But this does not change my end result of getting messages displayed to the screen on every update, just displaying on a handful of them.  I am going to try converting my web application from VS2010 - VS2015 and try again unless you have any other suggestions?

Comment: The only other thing that I know of that causes this type of behavior is if you are using dependency injection with signalr, This has been a known issue with signalr for a long time, and I do not know if there was ever a proper solution found for it.