# What are the best alternatives for Sqldependency in a n-layered architecture?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, push-notification, signalr, sqldependency

How to use Sqldependency like notifier in which it should be able to push notifications from a DB to Client in an n-layered architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use SqlDependecy triggers with signalr, here is an example

[Polling for database changes: SqlDependency, SignalR is Good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22198423/polling-for-database-changes-sqldependency-signalr-is-good/24250011#24250011)